# Inactive background when slidingdrawer is open

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I am working with slidingdrawer and was able to show the slidingdrawer on all activities in my application.

The issue i am facing is that i am still able to click on the background(views in the activity). Is there a way i can disable the background when slidingdrawer is open.

Regards

EDIT 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SlidingDrawer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Handle" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        style="@style/roundrectbox_white_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/slider_round_rect_border"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</SlidingDrawer>
```

Comment: what you have added as content of sliding drawer??

Comment: are you able to see listview when you drag sliding drawer??

Comment: My sliding drawer works perfectly and i am able to see the listview on draging it up. The issue is sliding drawer doesnt cover my whole content view and i am still able to click/tap on the background activity which i don't want. I want to disable it. I hope i am clear.

Comment: can u post ur xml file??

Comment: By doing this you wont be able to touch background contents.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello"/>

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="440dp"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/wood" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             >

                <ListView 
                    android:id="@+id/list"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in activity:

```
ListView listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        ArrayAdapter<String>  adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

where array is:

```
String[] array={"1","2","3","4"};
```